# Sesame configured with MySql support

Tags: mysql, configure, sesame, triplestore

I am using Sesame as triple store; I want to persist the triples in a MySQL database. In sesame 2.6.10 I added the mysql-connector-java-5.1.22-bin.jar inside the WEB-INF\lib\ folder, and everything went fine - I was able to declare mysql repositories and add contents via the sesame-workbench GUI.

I tried the same maneuver for Sesame 2.7.4 and 2.7.3, but I encounter a lot of errors. When I try to create the repository in workbench's "new repository" page, I am redirected to a web page with the following errors:

> > type Exception report
>
> message
>
> description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented
>   it from fulfilling this request.
>
> exception
>
> javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.ServletException:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>     org.openrdf.workbench.base.TransformationServlet.service(TransformationServlet.java:116)
>     org.openrdf.workbench.base.BaseServlet.service(BaseServlet.java:136)
>     org.openrdf.workbench.proxy.ProxyRepositoryServlet.service(ProxyRepositoryServlet.java:104)
>     org.openrdf.workbench.proxy.WorkbenchServlet.service(WorkbenchServlet.java:222)
>     org.openrdf.workbench.proxy.WorkbenchServlet.handleRequest(WorkbenchServlet.java:151)
>     org.openrdf.workbench.proxy.WorkbenchServlet.service(WorkbenchServlet.java:119)
>     org.openrdf.workbench.proxy.WorkbenchGateway.service(WorkbenchGateway.java:131)
>     org.openrdf.workbench.base.BaseServlet.service(BaseServlet.java:136)
>     org.openrdf.workbench.proxy.CookieCacheControlFilter.doFilter(CookieCacheControlFilter.java:63)
>
> root cause
>
> javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NullPointerException
>     org.openrdf.workbench.commands.CreateServlet.doPost(CreateServlet.java:78)
>     org.openrdf.workbench.base.TransformationServlet.service(TransformationServlet.java:106)
>     org.openrdf.workbench.base.BaseServlet.service(BaseServlet.java:136)
>     org.openrdf.workbench.proxy.ProxyRepositoryServlet.service(ProxyRepositoryServlet.java:104)
>     org.openrdf.workbench.proxy.WorkbenchServlet.service(WorkbenchServlet.java:222)
>     org.openrdf.workbench.proxy.WorkbenchServlet.handleRequest(WorkbenchServlet.java:151)
>     org.openrdf.workbench.proxy.WorkbenchServlet.service(WorkbenchServlet.java:119)
>     org.openrdf.workbench.proxy.WorkbenchGateway.service(WorkbenchGateway.java:131)
>     org.openrdf.workbench.base.BaseServlet.service(BaseServlet.java:136)
>     org.openrdf.workbench.proxy.CookieCacheControlFilter.doFilter(CookieCacheControlFilter.java:63)
>
> root cause
>
> java.lang.NullPointerException
>     org.openrdf.workbench.commands.CreateServlet.getConfigTemplate(CreateServlet.java:159)
>     org.openrdf.workbench.commands.CreateServlet.createRepositoryConfig(CreateServlet.java:130)
>     org.openrdf.workbench.commands.CreateServlet.doPost(CreateServlet.java:75)
>     org.openrdf.workbench.base.TransformationServlet.service(TransformationServlet.java:106)
>     org.openrdf.workbench.base.BaseServlet.service(BaseServlet.java:136)
>     org.openrdf.workbench.proxy.ProxyRepositoryServlet.service(ProxyRepositoryServlet.java:104)
>     org.openrdf.workbench.proxy.WorkbenchServlet.service(WorkbenchServlet.java:222)
>     org.openrdf.workbench.proxy.WorkbenchServlet.handleRequest(WorkbenchServlet.java:151)
>     org.openrdf.workbench.proxy.WorkbenchServlet.service(WorkbenchServlet.java:119)
>     org.openrdf.workbench.proxy.WorkbenchGateway.service(WorkbenchGateway.java:131)
>     org.openrdf.workbench.base.BaseServlet.service(BaseServlet.java:136)
>     org.openrdf.workbench.proxy.CookieCacheControlFilter.doFilter(CookieCacheControlFilter.java:63)
>
> note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the JBoss
>   Web/7.0.13.Final logs.

What should I do? I am using JBoss AS 7.1.1 final on Windows 7 x64.

Thanks.

Comment: Duplicate of question asked (and answered) on Sesame user mailinglist. See https://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/message.php?msg_id=31263379

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A workaround fix was included in Sesame to deal with your issue, will be avaiable in the upcoming release. However, as also pointed out on the mailinglist (see comment), Sesame 2.7 has deprecated the MySQL store. I recommend you switch to a different storage backend (such as the Native Store).